# How to replace values in an object with values from a list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following object and list:

```
myObj = [
          { width: 10, height: 15, length: 20 },
          { width: 8, height: 10, length: 10 },
          { width: 23, height: 5, length: 5 },
          { width: 11, height: 18, length: 10 }
        ];
heights = {12,13,14,15};
```

In Javascript or jQuery what is the best way to replace the object heights with the values in the heights list? The order does matter. Results should be:

```
 myObj = [
              { width: 10, height: 12, length: 20 },
              { width: 8, height: 13, length: 10 },
              { width: 23, height: 14, length: 5 },
              { width: 11, height: 15, length: 10 }
            ];
```

Comment: That is the wrong way to make an array. It should be `heights = [12, 13, 14, 15]`

Comment: It should definitely be an array. Your current code gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop, and assign the values

```js
var myObj = [{
    width: 10,
    height: 15,
    length: 20
}, {
    width: 8,
    height: 10,
    length: 10
}, {
    width: 23,
    height: 5,
    length: 5
}, {
    width: 11,
    height: 18,
    length: 10
}];
var heights = [12, 13, 14, 15];

myObj.forEach( function(obj,i){
    obj.height = heights[i]
});
console.log(myObj)

document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myObj)
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```